# Trying to understand 'mysqli_fetch_array' I fail to run an example

Tags: mysqli

The following code is the most simple I could get to make me understand how to work with 'mysqli_fetch_array'.

```
<?php
require ('mysqli_connect.php'); 
$sql="SELECT 'fname', 'email', 'pass' FROM 'list'";
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
while ($row !== NULL)
{
echo $row[0] . '. ' . $row[1] . ' ' . $row[2];
echo '<br />';
}
mysqli_close($dbcon);
?>
```

That code produces the following error message:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\mysqli_connect_test.php on line 5
```

Can anyone advise me how to make that code work? What "MYSQLI_NUM" stands for?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is plenty wrong with your code. Observe:

```
require 'mysqli_connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT `fname`, `email`, `pass` FROM `list`"; // #1
$result = $dbcon->query($sql); // #2
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) // #3
{
    echo "{$row[0]}. {$row[1]}. {$row[2]}<br>";
}
$dbcon->close();
```

Note #1: `''` is invalid wrapper for MySQL object names. `''` should be used to wrap strings only. Also, you don't really have to wrap them unless the object names happen to be reserved words.

Note #2: You must execute the query to generate `$result`.

Note #3: You must run `fetch_array()` every loop and not just once otherwise the value of `$row` will never change and it will be an infinite loop.

Consider using the `mysqli` class methods instead of the stand-alone functions. The code looks cleaner and makes more sense. Those functions like `mysqli_query()` are just for backward compatibility with `call_user_func()` and `call_user_func_array()`.

Comment: Thank you very much havenard. I repaired the code as you suggested and it is working now !

Answer (score 0):

The part of you code you shared i can see you didn't defined $result variable make sure you define that variable with mysqli_query()

```
<?php
$con =require ('mysqli_connect.php'); 
$sql="SELECT 'fname', 'email', 'pass' FROM 'list'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);//You forgot to define this variable
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
while ($row !== NULL)
{
echo $row[0] . '. ' . $row[1] . ' ' . $row[2];
echo '<br />';
}
mysqli_close($dbcon);
?>
```

mysqli_query is the function that executes you sql command. If you omit that nothing gona work.